# How to make the font of theorem number independent of the theorem head font

Tags: theorems, amsthm, elsarticle

When using `amsthm` with the `elsarticle` class, font of the number after theorem head depends on its font. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{rem}a remark.\end{rem}
\end{document}
```

Will results in

> *Remark 1*. a remark.

However, the usage of amsthm yields

> *Remark* 1. a remark.

**I wonder what cause the number font depends on the theorem head and how to make it independent (as in the usual amsthm)?**

Comment: I get upright 1

Comment: Similar to me, @egreg